# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok I have edited the code to where it would hopefully work but I get the TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.

Heres the code that I have:

```
uTemp = input("Enter Temperature Variable: ")

cOrF = input("Do you want C for celcius, or F for Farehnheit?: ")

if cOrF:
    F = 1.8 * uTemp + 32
```

Comment: This question has been answered.  Ask a new question if you have a new problem.  (Searching first is a good idea, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is telling you that you can't multiply `uTemp`, a string, by a floating-point number (`1.8`). Which makes perfect sense, right? What is eight tenths of a string? Convert `uTemp` to a float:

```
uTemp = float(input("Enter Temperature Variable: "))
```

Your next problem is that `cOrF` is treated as a Boolean (true/false) value, which means `F` will be calculated if the user enters *anything* at that prompt since all non-empty strings are truthy in Python. So instead you would write:

```
if cOrF == "F":
    F = 1.8 * uTemp + 32
```

Comment: it's still saying cOrF is an invalid syntax

Answer (score 6):

`input()` returns a string in python 3.x.

Convert it to `float` (or to `int` - depends on your needs):

```
uTemp = float(input("Enter Temperature Variable: "))
```

Comment: @user2755799 kindall explained what s better to do with `c0rf`, please check.