# can't multiple sequence by non-int of type float, float() argument must be a string or number

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I'm having some trouble with multiplying a vector entry times a constant. Basically I want to take a list, and multiply every entry in that list times a constant.

> For example: 4 * [1,2,3] would be [4, 8, 12].

I tried to do this the most straightforward way I knew how, simply by just writing the constant * the list I wanted to multiply by. However, this yielded the whole *can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*. I looked at a few questions about the issue ([TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668203/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float-3-3), and [can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612378/cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float)) and the only applicable solution I could find was to just use `float()`. However, when I tried doing that, I got another

> error: *float() argument must be a string or number, not 'tuple'*

. I'm at a lost of what to do here, I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this but I'm not sure what it is.

```
if n == m:

    if n == 1:
        denom = float(r1) * const
        ans = identity / denom
        return(ans)
```

This is the code that returns that error, and this is the code that returns the first error.

```
if n == 1:
        denom = r1 * const
        ans = identity / denom
        return(ans)
```

const is an earlier defined variable in the function, and r1 is also earlier defined as:

```
r1 = (1,1,1) #the starting position of the 3 particles: r1, r2, and r3
```

(the comment is there because I go on to define r2 and r3 afterwards.)

This isn't a homework assignment, so don't have any moral obligations to providing code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. For example, list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [(4.3 * x) for x in l]
[4.3, 8.6, 12.899999999999999]
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just curious, how would I do this for division? The next line immediately after is division. Here's what I have so far:

    `ans = 1/denom
            return(ans)`
However, it returns the error message _"unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'"_. If I'm trying to implement your solution, the code is now:


    `ans = [(1 / denom) for x in denom]
            return(ans)`

but again this returns the very same error. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
>>> z = [l * 4 for l in [1, 2, 3]];
>>> z
[4, 8, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just curious, how would I do this for division? The next line immediately after is division. Here's what I have so far:

    `ans = 1/denom
            return(ans)`
However, it returns the error message _"unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'"_. If I'm trying to implement your solution, the code is now:


    `ans = [(1 / denom) for x in denom]
            return(ans)`

but again this returns the very same error. Could you help me with this?